# How To Display Specific Range For Y Values Using ASP.NET Charts (MS Charts)

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm using ASP.NET charts for the first time and am having great success. The one thing I'm wanting to do is zoom in on my chart so that the y values don't go from 0-100. For example, Say I have some point values ranging from 72 to 89. What I'd like to do is have the lowest y value be 72 and the highest y value be 89 on the y axis (it's currently displaying 0 as the lowest and 100 as the highest). Here's the code I'm using:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" ImageLocation="~/content/images/temp/charts/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" Height="325px" Width="900px" runat="server">
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Text="Overview" Font="Arial, 12pt, style=Bold" />
    </Titles>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Font="Segoe UI, 8pt" Alignment="Center" BorderWidth="1" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#C6C6C6" Docking="Bottom" />
    </Legends>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY LineColor="#C6C6C6" IsInterlaced="true" InterlacedColor="#F0F0F0">
                <LabelStyle Font="Segoe UI, 8pt" ForeColor="#787878" />
                <MajorGrid LineColor="#C6C6C6" />
            </AxisY>
            <AxisX LineColor="#C6C6C6">
                <LabelStyle Font="Segoe UI, 8pt" ForeColor="#787878" />
                <MajorGrid LineColor="#C6C6C6" />
            </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var series = new Series("Overview")
    {
        Name = "Series1",
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
        MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle,
        MarkerSize = 7,
        XValueType = ChartValueType.Date,
        YValueType = ChartValueType.Double,                     
    };

    foreach (var survey in Surveys)
    {
        series.Points.AddXY(String.Format("{0:MMM yyyy}", survey.Month), survey.Score);
    }

    Chart1.Series.Add(series);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the [Minimum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum.aspx) and [Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum.aspx) properties of the [AxisY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.axisy.aspx) property of your [ChartArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.aspx).

So, in your `Page_Load` code (or wherever you need / prefer it), you could do something like this:

```
ChartArea1.AxisY.Minimum = 72;
ChartArea1.AxisY.Maximum = 89;
```

You can set some other cool things (like set the [Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval.aspx)) from that `AxisY` / `AxisX` property.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the know-how. There are so many properties that I honestly had no idea what to look for. This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Halcyon Don't I know it!  I just happened to know about that control from using it before.  That's what's so awesome about this site =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use this in combination with AJAX and the normal method kept crashing the page:

```
ChartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 100;
ChartArea.AxisY.Maximum = 100;
```

I was able to get it using this instead:

```
AxisScaleView yAxisScaleView = new AxisScaleView();
yAxisScaleView.Size = 100;
ChartArea.AxisY.ScaleView = yAxisScaleView;
```