# How to set the scale of your X Axis and Y Axis in MS Chart?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mschart

I have  a requirement to make the X-Axis and Y-Axis intersect at the middle of my chart created using MS-Chart.

The scale for both X and Y axis needs to be set based on the data points being returned from the Web Service.
How to do it programmatically using MS Chart?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Display Specific Range For Y Values Using ASP.NET Charts (MS Charts)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187489/how-to-display-specific-range-for-y-values-using-asp-net-charts-ms-charts)

Answer (score 3):

ok there are properties to set the minimum, maximum, and interval of all of the scales associated with a chart.  they are located something like the following:

```
chart1.ChartAreas(ChartAreaName).AxisX.Mimimum
chart1.ChartAreas(ChartAreaName).AxisX.Maximum
chart1.ChartAreas(ChartAreaName).AxisX.Interval
chart1.ChartAreas(ChartAreaName).AxisY.Mimimum
chart1.ChartAreas(ChartAreaName).AxisY.Maximum
chart1.ChartAreas(ChartAreaName).AxisY.Interval
```

you can use those combined with the dimensions of your chart to display any kind of scale you would like.